# Xamarin Android control specific unit padding

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to create padding on a TextView during run-time, so that it looks the same on all devices.

I have 2 TextView's that are placed next to each other horizontally inside a RelativeLayout. The first TextView is located on the left side of the layout and I want the other TextView to have a left margin or padding of let's say 200.

But what is 200? When I set this value in the XAML-file I can specify the units, but when I set it during run-time, and this it what I need to do, then I can only specify int values.

I can't find where to specify the unit type, so I can make this look at same on all screen resolutions.

Any help appreciated :)

Comment: i guess it should be dp, what you also should use on xml

Comment: I am, but as you can see, it is in run-time I need to do this - aka from code, not in the XAML.

Comment: i dont understand the problem, do it with code then, unit type should be in dp

Comment: ... yes, but where do I specify that it should be "dp". The SetPadding method only takes int values.

Comment: propably is on dp, you dont have to worry about it

Comment: Hmm then it's something else that is causing the problem because what I'm seeing (on 3 different devices) is that there is a desired space between the 1st and the 2nd TextView, but on a 4th device, they overlap by maybe 5 millimeters - so here the margin value is too small apparently.

Comment: what is the resolution of the 4th device and what on the others?

Comment: The 4th device has a resolution of 1440 x 2560.

Comment: google suggest different margin on very high resolutions https://material.io/guidelines/layout/responsive-ui.html#responsive-ui-breakpoints

Comment: I'm gonna take a look at it and also see if I can use the screen width for something with percentage. - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this is a real pain.  I have a solution that, as of right now, is not in a nice NuGet package. It will be in the next few weeks, but for now you'll have to do all the code yourself.

First, you need a public (PCL) interface:

```
public interface ILayoutService
{
    double GetScaledDouble(double original);
    int GetScaledInt32(int original);
}
```

Next, in your Android-specific code, you need an implementation of this interface:

```
public sealed class AndroidLayoutService : ILayoutService
{
    private static double s_standardWidthInches = 3.75;
    private static double s_widthScaleFactor = (double)Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / (double)Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi / s_standardWidthInches;

    public AndroidLayoutService()
    {
    }

    public double GetScaledDouble(double fontSize)
    {
        return fontSize * s_widthScaleFactor;
    }

    public int GetScaledInt32(int original)
    {
        return (int)(GetScaledDouble(original));
    }
}
```

Now get that implementation into a DI container of your choice.  My choice is the [OpenNETCF IoC](https://www.nuget.org/packages/com.opennetcf.ioc.pcl/) and that's what these examples will use, but you can use whatever mechanism you want - you'll have to adjust as needed.  Basically you have to get that from the Android-native bit over to your Xamarin Forms PCL.

So I do this:
    RootWorkItem.Services.Add();

Now, over in your PCL, you'll need a Markup Extension that can take a string and convert it to a thickness through this scaling mechanism.  It looks like this (note the DI container use - you may have to change that depending on your choice):

```
public sealed class ScaledThickness : IMarkupExtension
{
    private static ILayoutService s_layoutService = OpenNETCF.IoC.RootWorkItem.Services.Get<ILayoutService>();

    public string Thickness { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (s_layoutService == null)
        {
            var tc = new ThicknessTypeConverter();
            return tc.ConvertFromInvariantString(Thickness);
        }

        var sizeStrings = Thickness.Split(',');
        var sizes = new int[sizeStrings.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < sizes.Length; i++)
        {
            sizes[i] = s_layoutService.GetScaledInt32(Convert.ToInt32(sizeStrings[i]));
        }

        switch (sizes.Length)
        {
            case 1:
                return new Thickness(sizes[0]);
            case 2:
                return new Thickness(sizes[0], sizes[1]);
            case 4:
                return new Thickness(sizes[0], sizes[1], sizes[2], sizes[3]);
        }

        throw new Exception("Unable to convert to ScaledThickness: " + Thickness);
    }
}
```

Now, you consume all of this by doing something like this.  I'm using a Style for code clarity:

```
<Style x:Key="alarmRow" TargetType="Label">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{opennetcf:ScaledThickness Thickness='10,50,10,50'}" />
</Style>
```

What does this mess of code do?  When the `Label` (defined in XAML) is rendered, the markup is run though the extension.  The Thickness provided in the style gets first converted to 4 numbers: 10, 50, 10 and 50.  Those are run through a scaling factor determined by the ILayoutService and then used to create a Thickness object, which is then passed to the constructor of the `Label`.  Yep, it seem convoluted, but it works.  It looks right on small phones and large tablets, and with an iOS ILayoutService, it works there too, all with one code base.

Again, I apologize it's not in an easier to use form - I'll be pushing all of this up to the OpenNETCF Xamarin Forms NuGet package in the next few weeks so all you'd have to do is that very last bit of consuming the ScaledThickness but in the meantime, this is all I have.